# Can I place GridLayout in KeyboardView?

Tags: android, xml, android-softkeyboard, grid-layout, ime

Is there a way to have a GridLayout with some pictures in KeyboardView in Android? I have tried to write it in xml but it gives me error that I cant have that element in KeyboardView.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `KeyboardView` then?

Create an `InputMethodService` and in `onCreateInputView()`, return whatever layout you want to display.

```
@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
        final View root = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_layout, null);         

         //set all the click listeners for your views

        return root;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to put emojis in gridview, but then I added those in keyboardview. Now there are emoji keys but I have to fix encoding errors because when user clicks on emoji key it prints some chinese letter. Do you know what should I do to fix this?